# How can call function from object?

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I write a login form validation with formValidation. Now I want call this function in my script. How can I call form_login function?

```
(function(){
  $.fn.validation = {
    form_login: function(form){
         $(form).formValidation({
                icon: {
                    valid: 'fa fa-check',
                    invalid: 'fa fa-remove',
                    validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
                },
            fields: {
                usernme: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {},
                    }
                },
                password: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {},
                    }
                },
                captcha: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {},
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },
  };
 }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of usage for something similar with your code ( shorter ):

```
$.fn.test={
    test_method: function(){alert('a');}
}

var div= "<div></div>";
$(div).test.test_method(); // it will output that alert
```